# schemalocation in xml not getting validated against xsd

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

I have a schemalocation in the header of the xml. The xsd is not accepting the schemalocation in the xml. I am getting the following error.

SchemaLocation: SchemaLocation Value = 'http://localhost/test/ns/test.xsd' Must Have Even Number Of URI's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/test/ http://localhost/test/ns/test.xsd"
```

schemalocation needs 2 values (=even): namespaceuri + xsdlocation